# Change button and add a form on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a 'Pending' button. Which does nothing. Awesome. But what I'd like to do is when a user hovers over it, have a `<form>` appear and change the 'Pending' to 'Cancel'.

http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/

I'm not a js pro by any means. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Suggestions?

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: can you please give your html hear ?

Comment: see my answer below, should meet your needs and is quite clear markup imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to do it is to use the `.hover()` function in jquery.

```
$(function(){
    $('button').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).html('Cancel').removeClass("pending").addClass("cancel");
        },
        function(){
            $(this).html('Pending').removeClass("cancel").addClass("pending");
        }
    );
});​
```

check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Guess you missed the `$`?

```
$(function(){
    function revealButton(shown, hidden) {
        $(shown).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).parent().next().children(hidden).show();
        });

        $(hidden).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    };
    revealButton("button.pending", "button.cancel");
}());​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/1/

#### Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/5/

Comment: No the cancel button still shows... I need it to replace the pending.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/4/

Well, initially cancel is shown, but you may add a display:none  on your button.cancel in HTML. Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/7/)

```
(function(){
    function revealButton(shown, hidden) {
        $(shown).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).parent().next().children(hidden).show();
            $(shown).hide();
        });

        $(hidden).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(shown).show();
        });
    };
    revealButton("button.pending", "button.cancel");
}());​
```

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/8/)*

Changed HTML:

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="yaddaydahdasda">
        <button class="pending">Pending</button>
        <button type="submit" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
    
        token here
        <input type="hidden" value="myvalue" />       
    </form>
</div>
```

Added to CSS:

```
.cancel{
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    /* ... */
}
```

Fixed jQuery:

```
(function(){
    
    function revealButton(shown, hidden) {
        $(shown).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).next( $(hidden) ).show(); // fixed
        });

        $(hidden).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
    revealButton(".pending", ".cancel");
    
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but this is my best guess:

http://jsfiddle.net/ym4SK/

```
(function(){
    function revealButton(shown, hidden) {
        $(hidden).hide();
        $(shown).hover(function()
                       {
                           $(hidden).show();
                           $(shown).hide();
                       }, function() {});
        $(hidden).hover(function() {}, function()
                        {
                           $(shown).show();
                           $(hidden).hide();
                        });
    };
    revealButton("button.pending", "button.cancel");
}());​
```

Note: it's best to use `hover` for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

heres something, all code here instead of fiddle.

First of all, as your question decleares, you want to Pending button change to Cancel, so im stripped another button from html

```
<div>
    <input type='submit' class="pending" value='Pending' />
</div>
<form method="POST" action="yaddaydahdasda" id="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="myvalue" />
</form>​
```

now some jQuery action.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // if jquery dosent load for some reason, form will be visible. Thats why we hide it when on DOM ready
        $("#form").hide();

    });

    $(".pending").on('mouseover',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('pending').addClass('cancel');
        $(this).val('Cancel');
        $("#form").show();
    });

    $(".pending").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $(".cancel").on('click',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('cancel').addClass('pending');
        $(this).val('Pending');
        $("#form").hide();
    });
```

Thats about it! Works like a charm! You might want to add some css to form, eg. make it float next to button or something?